# Как возвращать false в методах удаления связного списка ?

Tags: javascript

**Методы удаления:**

- removeFirst() - удаления сначала (возвращает удаленное значение, как возвратить false если такого значения в списке нет
- `removeLast()` - удаление с конца (возвращает удаленное значение, как возвратить false если такого значения в списке нет)

Весь мой код:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value; // value in the node
        this.next = null; // link to the next node
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        /*pointer to the knot-head
        (first element) of the list*/
        this.head = null;
        /*pointer to the node-tail
        (last item) of the list*/
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

//insert to the beginning (returns the inserted value)
    addFirst(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.head) {
            newNode.next = this.head;
            //this.head = newNode;
        } else {//Linked list is empty
            this.tail = newNode;
            //this.head = newNode
        }
        //set the head to the new node
        this.head = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

//insert to the end(returns the inserted value)
    addLast(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.head = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode
        }
        this.tail = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }
/*delete from the beginning (returns the deleted value, or false
if there is no such value in the list)*/
    removeFirst() {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            // The head should point to the second element
            this.head = this.head.next;
            this.length--;
            if (this.length === 0) {
                // If list empty, set tail to null
                this.tail = null;
            }
        }
    }
/*delete from the end (returns the deleted value,
or false if there is no such value in the list)*/
    removeLast() {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            if (this.length === 1) {
                this.head = null;
                this.tail = null;
            } else {
                // Find the Node right before the last Node
                let current = this.head;
                while (current.next !== this.tail) {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                current.next = null;
                this.tail = current;
            }
            this.length--;
        }
    }
}
let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
// list.addFirst('1');
// list.addLast('2');
// list.addLast('3');
// list.removeFirst();
list.removeFirst();
console.log(list);
```

Comment: `else { return false; }`

Comment: пробовал, не работает

Comment: Плохо пробовал. все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно [Грундь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843197/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-false-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0#comment1353186_843197) подсказал: возвращайте `false` после проверки на (от-) присутствие нужного узла.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value; // value in the node
        this.next = null; // link to the next node
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        /*pointer to the knot-head
        (first element) of the list*/
        this.head = null;
        /*pointer to the node-tail
        (last item) of the list*/
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

//insert to the beginning (returns the inserted value)
    addFirst(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.head) {
            newNode.next = this.head;
            //this.head = newNode;
        } else {//Linked list is empty
            this.tail = newNode;
            //this.head = newNode
        }
        //set the head to the new node
        this.head = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

//insert to the end(returns the inserted value)
    addLast(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.head = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode
        }
        this.tail = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }
/*delete from the beginning (returns the deleted value, or false
if there is no such value in the list)*/
    removeFirst() {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            // The head should point to the second element
            this.head = this.head.next;
            this.length--;
            if (this.length === 0) {
                // If list empty, set tail to null
                this.tail = null;
            }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
/*delete from the end (returns the deleted value,
or false if there is no such value in the list)*/
    removeLast() {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            if (this.length === 1) {
                this.head = null;
                this.tail = null;
            } else {
                // Find the Node right before the last Node
                let current = this.head;
                while (current.next !== this.tail) {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                current.next = null;
                this.tail = current;
            }
            this.length--;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
}
let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
// list.addFirst('1');
// list.addLast('2');
// list.addLast('3');
// list.removeFirst();
console.log(list.removeFirst());
```